# Bash conditionally split string into array

Tags: arrays, bash, split

I've browsed questions for splitting input based on a character but can't quite figure out multiple characters based on a condition:

Say I had a simply bash script that split input separated by spaces into an array:

```
echo "Terms:"
read terms            // foo bar hello world
array=(${terms// / }) // ["foo", "bar", "hello", "world"]
```

I want an extra condition where if terms are encapsulated by another character, the whole phrase should be split as one.

e.g. encapsulated with a back tick:

```
echo "Terms:"
read terms            // foo bar `hello world`
{conditional here}    // ["foo", "bar", "hello world"]
```

Comment: There is no different delimiter in `foo bar \`hello world\``

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the clarification. I didn't get any concrete definition on what a delimiter according to bash so I assumed to the best of my knowledge it was synonymous with a character used to split input. I edited my question.

Comment: Backtick is used for command substitution in BASH or POSIX. You probably can use single quotes like `foo bar 'hello world'`

Comment: Interesting, good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a delimiter other than whitespace for the call to `read`:

```
$ IFS=, read -a array   # foo,bar,hello world
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
foo
bar
hello world
```

You should probably be using the `-r` option with `read`, but since you aren't, you *could* have the user escape their own spaces:

```
$ read -a array    # foo bar hello\ world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your input to a function and make use of `$@` to build your array:

```
makearr() { arr=( "$@" ); }

makearr foo bar hello world
# examine the array
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="hello" [3]="world")'

# unset the array
unset arr

makearr foo bar 'hello world'
# examine the array again
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="hello world")'
```